# no matching function for call to 'WaveHC::WaveHC()' Arduino Error

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I'm working on a arduino(uno) talking clock project. I'm using the code on this site : https://learn.adafruit.com/wave-shield-talking-clock/overview

add the WaveHC library when I get the following error :

```
Arduino:1.6.6 (Windows 10), Card:"Arduino/Genuino Uno"
TalkingClock:44: error: no matching function for call to 'WaveHC::WaveHC()'
 WaveHC     wave;
            ^
\Arduino\TalkingClock\TalkingClock.ino:44:12: note: candidates are:
In file included from \Arduino\TalkingClock\TalkingClock.ino:26:0:
\Arduino\libraries\WaveHC/WaveHC.h:113:3: note: WaveHC::WaveHC(HardwareSerial&)
   WaveHC(HardwareSerial& serial);
   ^
\Arduino\libraries\WaveHC/WaveHC.h:113:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
\Arduino\libraries\WaveHC/WaveHC.h:77:7: note: constexpr WaveHC::WaveHC(const WaveHC&)
 class WaveHC
       ^
\Arduino\libraries\WaveHC/WaveHC.h:77:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
\Arduino\libraries\WaveHC/WaveHC.h:77:7: note: constexpr WaveHC::WaveHC(WaveHC&&)
\Arduino\libraries\WaveHC/WaveHC.h:77:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
TalkingClock:64: error: variable 'hours' must be const in order to be put into read-only section by means of '__attribute__((progmem))'
   *hours[]  = { h12, h01, h02, h03, h04, h05, h06, h07, h08, h09, h10, h11 },
          ^
TalkingClock:65: error: variable 'mTens' must be const in order to be put into read-only section by means of '__attribute__((progmem))'
   *mTens[]  = { m00, m10, m20, m30, m40, m50 },
          ^
TalkingClock:66: error: variable 'mTeens' must be const in order to be put into read-only section by means of '__attribute__((progmem))'
   *mTeens[] = { m11, m12, m13, m14, m15, m16, m17, m18, m19 },
           ^
TalkingClock:67: error: variable 'mTenX' must be const in order to be put into read-only section by means of '__attribute__((progmem))'
   *mTenX[]  = { m0x, NULL, m2x, m3x, m4x, m5x },
          ^
TalkingClock:68: error: variable 'mins' must be const in order to be put into read-only section by means of '__attribute__((progmem))'
   *mins[]   = { m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8, m9 },
         ^
TalkingClock:69: error: variable 'ampm' must be const in order to be put into read-only section by means of '__attribute__((progmem))'
   *ampm[]   = { am, pm };
         ^
exit status 1
no matching function for call to 'WaveHC::WaveHC()'
```

Comment: I solve problems, I wrote as follows :
1) https://wavehc.googlecode.com/files/wavehc20090418.zip
This link is different WaveHC library. I changed it with the old,

2) I installed version 1.0.5 of Arduino